# Full text search in H2 problem with like clause?

Tags: full-text-search, h2

I have created Full-Text search index for my **H2** database.
and i can execute following queries like

`stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FT_SEARCH_DATA('abc', 0, 0)")`

(refer to [this example](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/test/org/h2/test/db/TestFullText.java))
and this returns the query to find the record with `abc` string.

How can I make the query search the word in between? I want to use the `like` clause (`like %abc%`) in the query.

Comment: Erm...by changing your SQL? Not entirely sure what you're asking here. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: How can i use like clause in Full Text Search Query [for h2 DB]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you make a concrete example, with real data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The H2 Database  [Native Fulltext Search](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#fulltext) feature allows searches for [key words in context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Word_in_Context). You can examine the words in your index using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM FT.WORDS;
```

Using [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/features.html) may be better suited to wild-card searches.

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expressions in h2 database SELECT. I think you will be interested in something like:

`SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE name regexp '.*abc.*'`